# How is the Riemann Hypothesis related to P vs NP?

Tags: riemann-hypothesis

Are the Riemann Hypothesis and P vs NP related?  It seems that if there is an algorithm to find the distribution of primes without factoring every number would be a polynomial time solution? I am admittedly not a mathematician so this might be a silly question.

Comment: Prime factorization is not (known to be) NP-complete. Also RH does not provide a better algorithm to find the primes, or to factor numbers.

Comment: Thanks, that basically answers the question.  On a somewhat unrelated note wouldn't proving that prime factorization is in fact a P class problem be as big of a deal as proving it is or is not NP-complete?  It might not solve P vs NP but demonstrating that it is definitely a P class would have some implications.

Comment: Yes, it would be a big deal, but wouldn't prove P=NP.

Comment: Prime is in fact in P : https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2928758_Primes_is_in_P

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS Primes (= telling if a number is prime) is not the same as prime *factorization*, though.